# Unhandled exception when running Tesseract OCR

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, tesseract, unhandled-exception

I am trying to use tesseract for the very first time and i get the following error when i compile:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x76F88F05 (ntdll.dll) in lpr.exe: 0xC0150002: 
Windows was not able to process the application binding information. 
Please refer to your System Event Log for further information.
```

Can anyone help me?

Here's the code :

```
char *outText;

tesseract::TessBaseAPI *api = new tesseract::TessBaseAPI();
// Initialize tesseract-ocr with English, without specifying tessdata path
if (api->Init(NULL, "eng")) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not initialize tesseract.\n");
    exit(1);
}

// Open input image with leptonica library
Pix *image = pixRead("B:\Projects\Visual 2013\lpr\lpr\placuta.jpeg");
api->SetImage(image);
// Get OCR result
outText = api->GetUTF8Text();
printf("OCR output:\n%s", outText);

// Destroy used object and release memory
api->End();
delete[] outText;
pixDestroy(&image);
```

Eventlog message:

> Activation context generation failed for "B:\Projects\Visual 2013\lpr\lpr\libtesseract302d.dll".
>
> Dependent Assembly `Microsoft.VC90.DebugCRT,processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e1‌​8e3b",type="win32",version="9.0.21022.8"` could not be found.
>
> Please use sxstrace.exe for detailed diagnosis.

Comment: One should not put tags in the title => http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130208/178881

Comment: I get the error on run. 
Even if i insert just this line in my project: "tessarct::TessBaseAPI *api= new tesseract::TessBaseAPI();"it still gives me the same error. 

system event log says:
"Activation context generation failed for "B:\Projects\Visual 2013\lpr\lpr\libtesseract302d.dll". Dependent Assembly Microsoft.VC90.DebugCRT,processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="9.0.21022.8" could not be found. Please use sxstrace.exe for detailed diagnosis."

Comment: Looks like you do not have the Visual C++ 2008 runtime distributables installed...

Comment: is this what i need to install ? :http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=29

Comment: i insalled it but no still it doesn't work, maybe i need to unninstall the other versions?

Comment: The VS 2008 redistributables aren't going to include the debug CRT libraries. You need to recompile your libtesseract302d DLL with your current copy of VS, if you can, so it can use the local debug CRT.

Comment: or maybe you guys know another method for OCR. I just need to recognize text from a binary image with letters and numbers. My project is about license plate reading.

Comment: This approach might work for building: http://vorba.ch/2014/tesseract-3.03-vs2013.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Colin Robertson

this did it for me : vorba.ch/2014/tesseract-3.03-vs2013.html –
After you follow the steps include your lib files downloaded from tesseract google, into yout project.